# How to create group by age employee in php myqsl

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to create `chart.js` for avarage age in my company. But I can't create the query.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, STR_TO_DATE(t.employee_birthday, '%Y-%m-%d'))/365 AS `ageInYears` 
FROM `employee` `t` 
WHERE `employee_birthday` BETWEEN `employee_birthday` = 20 and `employee_birthday` = 30
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: this calculate age for anyone

SELECT DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, STR_TO_DATE(t.employee_birthday, '%Y-%m-%d'))/365 AS `ageInYears` FROM `employee` `t`

Comment: probably you want `WHERE employee_birthday BETWEEN 20 and 30`.

Comment: I want to create a query where I do age calculations, group them and count them by age

Comment: You use `STR_TO_DATE(t.employee_birthday, '%Y-%m-%d'))/365` - does `t.employee_birthday` have a string type? You use ```employee_birthday` BETWEEN `employee_birthday` = 20 and `employee_birthday` = 30`` - what do `employee_birthday`s do in BETWEEN parameters?

Comment: SELECT DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, STR_TO_DATE(t.employee_birthday, '%Y-%m-%d'))/365 AS `ageInYears` FROM `employee` `t` GROUP BY if(`ageInYears` BETWEEN '20' and '30', 0, 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, `employee_birthday` is actually a date.  At last that would make sense to me.

If you want employees between 20 and 30, then the logic is something like this:

```
WHERE employee_birthday >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 YEAR AND
      employee_birthday < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 20 YEAR
```

Comment: SELECT DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, STR_TO_DATE(t.employee_birthday, '%Y-%m-%d'))/365 AS `ageInYears` FROM `employee` `t` WHERE employee_birthday <= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 20 YEAR AND employee_birthday > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 25 YEAR

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are not able to use ageInYears in comparison but you will able to get the result using the following query

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, STR_TO_DATE(t.employee_birthday, '%Y-%m-%d'))/365 AS ageInYears
FROM user t where t.employee_birthday != '' and DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, STR_TO_DATE(t.employee_birthday, '%Y-%m-%d'))/365  between 30 and 40
```

Comment: you need it to be like this ? I mean you need to calculate this different age group

Comment: Yes, you understand me

Comment: so you are running different queries to display the data ?

Comment: SELECT DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, STR_TO_DATE(t.dateOfBirth, '%Y-%m-%d'))/365 AS ageInYears
FROM user t where t.dateOfBirth != '' group by ageInYears

Comment: there is something you can change in your query like query BETWEEN 20 - 25 to query BETWEEN 20 and 25 , query BETWEEN 26 and 30 ,query BETWEEN 31 and  35 and this query > 20 must be  query between  20 and 24